# Update Custom product meta when order completed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to update a product meta for all products of each order that gets completed. Can you have a look at my approach below? Any help on why it is not working will be appreciated. I am new to all this php customizing.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'update_product_meta', 20, 2 );
function update_product_meta ( $order_id, $order ) {
    
        // GET USER ORDERS (COMPLETED + PROCESSING)
        $args = array(
         'post_status' => array('wc-completed')
        );
        $done_orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

    // LOOP THROUGH ORDERS AND GET PRODUCT IDS
    if ( $done_orders ) {
    $product_ids = array();
    foreach ( $done_orders as $done_order ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $done_order->ID );
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        }
    }
    
        add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'action_save_product_meta' );
function action_save_product_meta( $product_id ) {
    update_post_meta($product_id, 'Stav', 'Vypůjčeno' );
}
}
}
```

Comment: Why request ALL orders when it is only about the current order? you also do not take the current user into account, which means that all existing orders (orders that don't belong to the current user) are requested/updated, including all orders that have already been updated before/in the past

Answer (score 0):

Well you're pretty close, you just have to remove the nonsense at the end.

Something along the lines of:

```php
<?php

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', function ( $order_id, $order ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_status' => array('wc-completed')
    );

    $done_orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

    if ( ! empty( $done_orders ) ) {

        foreach ( $done_orders as $done_order ) {

            $order = wc_get_order( $done_order->ID );

            $items = $order->get_items();

            foreach ( $items as $item ) {

                $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

                update_post_meta( $product_id, 'Stav', 'Vypůjčeno' );

            };

        };

    };

}, 20, 2 );
```

You should think of limiting it to a specific amount because right now your query will request ALL items ever completed. be careful.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It is working. I am new to the php, so I was just hoping that adding more stuff will make it work... Thank you again!